# how to make a property can be mutated only inside its class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in programming and especially in Kotlin, I am sorry if my question is too basic

I need to make a property can be mutated only inside its class, but if other class access that property, I can only get the value but can't change it.

```
class Person {

    var name = ""

    fun changeName(newName: String) {
        name = newName
    }


}
```

but if I access this from other class, I still can change the name. I only want to get the value if it is accessed from other class

```
somePerson.name = "newNameIsNotAllowedHere"
```

but if I change the property to `val` then I am confused how to assign via method

```
class Person {

    val name = ""

    fun changeName(newName: String) {
        name = newName // can't assign new value because of val
    }


}
```

if using LiveData in Android, from tutorial I follow, I can do something like this, but I am confused how to apply the same behaviour in normal data type

```
    private val mIsLoadingData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoadingData : LiveData<Boolean>
        get() =  mIsLoadingData
```

Comment: Put `private set` on the line after the property declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pubic getter and a private setter:

```kotlin
class Person {

    var name: String = ""
        private set

}
```

Docs: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters